# Parameters and my own functions in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi to every one I'm new with symfony2, and i got two questions,

the first is: I need have 2 Parameters in one array,  for example

```
   $actions = array('1' => 'In', '2' => 'Out')
```

in all symfony2 in my bundle, where is the appropriate place/file to set this parameter, I've seen in symfony 1.4 put this parameter in some classes but in symfony2 I dont know wherw to put it because I just have the Entity DIR for classes.

The second is:

I need create my own functions to do something about a entity class for example Employees, I need to create a function to get the a especific employe and after do some proccess with its information a return a value, well the question is 

 Where I should put my own functions in my bundle ?

Any Suggestion I appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to 2<sup>nd</sup> question:
Symfony2 uses `ClassLoader` so if you will follow [coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/contributing/code/standards.html), you can put it anywhere, you want to (I recommend you to read [best practises](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html)). Just register namespace:

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Temp;

class MyClass
{
  public function getCertainEmployee($param)
  {}
}
```

One of possible way is to use `EntityRepository`.

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class EmployeeRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function getCertainEmployee($param)
  {}
}
```

The you can just call:

```
$certainEmployee = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getEntityRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Employee')
                        ->getCertainEmployee($foo)
;
```

Comment: ok thanks you, what is the function for the repository class of an object?